# Officer Career with philosophy degree

Tags: career-development

I'm considering after I graduate soon (USA) with a bachelor's in philosophy whether I'd like to go on to grad school or something else, and the subject of military officer came up. What would my best options be if I was interested in this path? I don't imagine there is much room for philosophy as a specialty in the military.

Comment: Welcome to the site Patrick. I want to point out that we generally encourage you not to accept an answer too quickly. You may want to give other people a chance to submit an answer as well and accepting early tends to discourage other people from replying. You are free to change or remove the mark-as-answered tick at any time and you may want to do so and wait [one or two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382) before evaluating the answers you received and accepting the one that you found the most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The military isn't a job, it is a lifestyle. You will need to be able to accept being away from home for months, maybe even years, on end. You have to be able to adapt to living in other countries. You have to be able to accept that in essence the job of the military is to defend the interests of your country and that means at gunpoint. You are risking your life, in some military professions, you risk daily even when not in a war zone (the flight deck of an aircraft carrier is a very dangerous place, for instance).

On the plus side, the military does training really well and whatever specialty you end up with (You don't always get to choose), they will train you very thoroughly how to do.

Philosophy is basically an analytical specialty, so whether civilian or military look at analytical positions. In the military, intelligence are often looking for people with an analytic bent. If you look at government service as an option look for the jobs that require a degree but do not specify what it has to be in such as management analyst. In large companies, go talk to HR about what general entry level positions their company tends to have to get a better idea of what is available in the private sector. Meeting planning is one thing that comes to mind that often looks for a degree a degree but not a specific one. And don't forget to check out the non-profit sector. They may be less likely to require a business-specific degree.

If you have time before you graduate, take some statistics and other data related classes. Big data is all about analyzing data and as I said philosophy (and all other liberal arts degrees) are all about analysis and all you need to be land the job might be some math as well as the philosophy. If you don't have time before you graduate to get credit classes, look at Coursera, they have big data certification programs and those can help you get a better job later and give you something productive to do while you look for a position.

You also do a fair amount of writing in philosophy classes so look for jobs that have a significant writing component.

My degree is in Political Science and I have never once had trouble landing a job with that degree and I work in a very technical field now. Don't buy into the myth that only Business and technical degrees lead to jobs. You do need to look at the types of skills you have gotten such as analysis and writing and market yourself to people and you may have to work a little harder for the first job, but you can get a job. Be sure to look outside the box when looking at entry level positions. It is more important to get your foot in the door and then prove yourself than to get the perfect first position. And nothing says that what you start out in is what you have to stay in.

Answer (score 5):

I think the general advice regarding any enlistment question is talk to a few recruiters. More than one or two because they will each have different perspectives and knowledge about different opportunities, try as they might to provide a unified appearance.

But in general, the majority of military vocations have nothing to do with the area of education practiced and this is normal. They key thing that higher education provides is a basic assessment of superior intelligence, critical reasoning, writing skills, and dedication. Certainly some trades like information security or aviation may be closed off to you, but fundamentally nothing would stop you from enlisting. Recruiters would be able to better answer what fulfilling career opportunities your degree would be eligible for.

Comment: Are there any civilian careers I might be on the lookout for?

Comment: I would add to this answer that in general the degree is mostly the "back-up plan" for if you ever choose to or are forced to end your military career.

Comment: So @Cronax if I consider this, I should be thinking military first philosophy second?

Comment: When considering military, even for free education, I would strongly advise you consider military above anything else. Despite all the perks, your number 1 job is to put your and your teammates's lives on the line. If you can't commit to that responsibility, any career after your contract will be meaningless.

Regarding civie careers in philosophy, I'm not sure and assume academia is it. Grad school isn't an easy choice. Maybe this podcast can help you there. http://verybadwizards.com/episodes/21

Comment: Patrick - I think the general military question is on topic.  What civilian job to take is not.